# The type provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2008

I had been getting the error "The type 'XXXNAMESPACEXXX.YYYCLASSYY', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found".

My .svc file:

```
<% @ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="XXXNAMESPACEXXX.YYYCLASSYY" %>
```

My .cs file:

```
namespace XXXNAMESPACEXXX
{
    public class YYYCLASSYY : ABC, XYZ
    {
.
.
.
```

I have a virtual directory created in my IIS and when I browse the service through IIS, it works fine. But when I right click the same svc file in visual studio 2008 and click on "View in browser", it throws the above error. Am using IIS 7.5, Windows 7.
Please help.

Answer (score -1):

I too got this error just now and modified the service attribute as below

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="EvalServiceLibrary.DoEmployee" CodeBehind="EvalServiceLibrary.IDoEmployee" %>
```